# Validation error: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validated my website and I keep getting this error, I have no idea how to get rid of it...

```
Error Line 64, Column 32: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
<label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
```

My code for that is

```
<label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
<label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is there an html element with id `img-6`?

Comment: No, would that be the reason why?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly the reason why.

Comment: Oh damn it, I'm a noob thanks for helping mate!